# Get summed value from specific rows

Tags: php, mysql, rows

I have this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT balance FROM " . MYSQLBTCTABLE . " WHERE address='" . $_POST['address'] . "' LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $balance = $row['balance'];

echo "<font style='font-weight:bold;'>Your current balance is: </font><br/>";
printf("%0.8f", ($balance / 100000000));
```

but it gets only the last value I need to find all balances from that address and sum them in total for the `$balance`.

Comment: Where are you closing the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Remove limit 1 and do the sum

        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT balance FROM " . MYSQLBTCTABLE . " WHERE      
        address='" . $_POST['address'] . "' ");
        $balance = 0;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           $balance += $row['balance'];
        echo "<font style='font-weight:bold;'>Your current balance is: </font><br/>";
        printf("%0.8f", ($balance / 100000000));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$balance += $row['balance'];
```

Comment: Well, that's half the answer

Comment: oh ya, there is a 'LIMIT 1' in the end which should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Use agregation:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT sum(balance) FROM " . MYSQLBTCTABLE . " WHERE address='" . $_POST['address'] . "' GROUP BY address");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `LIMIT` out of the query and add `SUM`

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT SUM(balance) as totalBalance FROM " . MYSQLBTCTABLE . " WHERE address='" . $_POST['address'] . "'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$balance = $row['totalBalance'];

echo "<font style='font-weight:bold;'>Your current balance is: </font><br/>";
printf("%0.8f", ($balance / 100000000));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all,instead :

```
$balance = $row['balance'];
```

use:

```
$balance += $row['balance'];
```

Furthermore, get rid of the "LIMIT 1" constraint

Comment: I've added SUM and I've removed limit and I added += it's working except that nasty error Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ...

Comment: only one more error it counts only to 999 when it reaches 1000 it restarts counting